# Different color in different ViewControllers in NavigationBar

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar, appdelegate

I have been facing problems with my navigation bar color. I used the below code

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.086 green:0.525 blue:0.427 alpha:1]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

in my `AppDelegate` to give a uniform color throughout. But it seems, there is some issue in its working as I'm getting a different shade in some `ViewControllers`.
Please check on the images below.
This should be the original color :

[image]

But in another `ViewController` I'm getting this :

[image]

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are setting some as Opaque and some as not, also some might be translucent.

Recheck them and you should get the same shade ;)